# What is the difference between changing properties in a class vs data in a Database?

Tags: sql, mysql, node.js, class, oop

One thing I struggle with when trying to write maintainable code is as follows :  When we store our data in properties using objects, we have methods which change the values of those properties. No other methods in other objects change those properties directly ,they only call methods from that object if it's passed in as a dependancy but its bad practice to directly access the properties of one object from another. This way when there is a change to a property we know it has come from inside the object that the property is in and makes our code easier to read and maintain and generally know better what's occuring.

Whereas if we store our data in a sql database it seems as though we do the total opposite. Instead we create classes in our app server using OOP and the behaviour of these classes can access the tables in the database from multiple different classes which means the data stored in the tables are accessible and change from any class ?

Should I be designing my classes to target a specific table, because at the moment I am grouping related behaviour in my classes which access various different tables without passing a dependancy object which may access a specific table ( something I wouldn't do if targeting properties from one object in another object).

I understand that in a normalised database we may have to perform joins or sub queries to extract specific data we require and Im fine with this, but sometimes from a class I run a sub query on a specific table which has no relations. For example, a board game, I have a dice table. It only ever has one row which is the last number rolled and a column to specify if the number rolled is a double or not. Should I be passing a dice class into the another class if I want to interact with the dice table , or can I simply just run a sub query in my sql statement from the class that needs the last number rolled to add to the current players board position. I have not created a separate Database Service Layer yet, I am instead sending my sql statements from the respective classes. Am I overthinking this and a database acts more like a DAO where I can access data from any class as I deem fit ?

Below is my query which updates the players square count by running a sub query into the dice table

```
async updateCurrentPlayersSquareCount(connection) {
  try {
    connection.execute(`UPDATE PLAYERS
    SET board_id = 
      CASE 
          WHEN  board_id + 
                (SELECT dice_score FROM dice) > 40 
          THEN  board_id + (SELECT dice_score FROM dice) - 40
          ELSE  board_id + (SELECT dice_score FROM dice)
      END
    WHERE id IN (SELECT player_turn FROM game_logic);`); 
  } catch (e) {
  throw new Error("couldnt add the dice score to the players count in the database");
  }
}
```

Comment: http://blogs.newardassociates.com/blog/2006/the-vietnam-of-computer-science.html

Comment: That `CASE` statement can be significantly simplified.  In the process you will probably fix the strange values you are getting.

Comment: @RickJames how would you write the query please? Thanks

Comment: @KevinGreetham - is there exactly 1 row in `dice`?

Comment: @RickJames yes one row consisting of the doubles rolled in a row and the latest score , but once the player goes round the board their square-count starts again. Thank for your help

Comment: `SET board_id = MOD(board_id + (SELECT dice_score FROM dice) -1, 40) + 1`  The +/-1 is because MOD wants to work with 0..39, but you want 1..40.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I be designing my classes to target a specific table

In short, yes.

You should consider your data tables as a store for instances of your classes.

Not all classes need tables, but all tables should have classes. Classes that do have tables are referred to in most frameworks as "Models" because they model the data.
In your case your players may be a model with a `players` table and a `Player` class.
Your boards may be a model with a `boards` table and a `Board` class. Perhaps you have many boards each with a different number of squares so each record in your `boards` table stores the number of squares for that board and your `Board` class is responsible for retrieving the number of squares when it's loaded as part of a game.

Consider classes that **don't** need a table such as `Dice` you don't need to store the result of a dice roll against the dice themselves. You can simply hardcode the possible outcomes and pick one at random when you call the `throw` method. The number of squares the player moves as a result of the dice throw should be stored as a move in the game.

`Games` on the other hand, need a table to store the state of the game over time.
Since one game may have greater or fewer moves than another, you may consider the `Game` as storing things like the players who are playing the game, the time the game started, the time it finished, and which player won.
While the moves may have their own table, with each move linking to a game by using the `game_id` and to the player by the `player_id`. Both the `Game` class and the `Player` class may have their own `move()` method that creates a related move. If you call `move()` on the game you would give it the *player* instance and number of squares

```
game.move(player, squares)
```

and if you call `move()` on the player you would give it the *game* instance and number of squares

```
player.move(game, squares)
```

Each class would create an a related instance of `Move` and the `Move` class would handle storing its data to the table.

Model classes that retrieve data from and store data to the database all share similar methods like `get` that retrieves the data or `save` that stores it. So you should consider that your model classes should inherit behaviour from a base `Model` class.

I would strongly recommend considering an *Object Relational Mapper* to handle your models' database interactions. I see your code example is node.js, maybe consider [Sequelize](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/understanding-nodejs-sequelize-orm-models/). The advantage of an ORM is that much of the logic of connecting to the DB and preparing queries to protect from SQL injection attacks etc. is done for you plus the documentation may help you get to grips with the concepts of relational databases and object models.

Hope this helps.

Comment: 1) The only problem I have with this however is that all my logic is done on the app server this way? And what about if I want to run a query which joins tables? My result set would now consist of various tables all within one Model? 2) inevitably non related tables may need to interact with each other, shall I pass some models in as dependancies to other or even have a mediator which accepts both models and provides the logic for the models to collaborate? If I do this won’t my result sets be larger than necessary making the app slower than if I just performed the logic on the database? Ta

Comment: can you assist. Thank you

Comment: This approach doesn't necessarily mean ALL the logic must be done on the server, just the logic that handles storing and retrieving data at the DB level. Your front end can have its own logic and use the server to push and pull data. In fact, you should never use client-side logic to interact directly with your DB

Comment: Where you need to join data from multiple tables you would most likely want to implement relationships, which most ORMs have features to handle. For example if you want to get all the moves from a game, the game model would have a relationship to the moves model and would load (when prompted) all the related data.

Comment: Finally, if you need to join two tables to get all the data for a single model, you can do so by implementing custom query logic. There's no reason a single model can't pull data from multiple joined tables, however, needing to do so might be an indication that your data structure could be improved

Comment: sorry what I meant by logic on the app server is not peforming logic on the database using more complex queries than just the retrieval and updating of data in a single table! I kind of get what your saying ,I’m not using an orm such as sequelize atm ,  I just feel like mapping classes to tables seems like I’m getting back chunks of data when I can minimise the response significantly by having a class access multiple tables. Your last point you said my data structure could be improved, but by storing data in multiple tables and relating them is an important aspect of normalisation?ta

Comment: Your question was very general and in the general case it's right to say that each table should correspond to a model and each model should be an analog of a real-world concept. When you need to pull data from multiple tables you most likely need to query a model with its related data for example a player with all of their games. In these cases the ORM should build a single query (or a minimal set of queries) that gets players and their associated games then map the results to a set of players each with an array of games. The ORM does all that work for you.

Comment: You can do the same as the ORM does by running a query to get your players then another to get games with players joined to get their associated player IDs. Then you would loop through the players and match up the games. Using an ORM just means you don't have to reinvent that wheel.

Comment: If you happen to have a need to join two tables to get data for a single concept. Let's say you have a `players` table and then `players_meta` and your Player model isn't complete until you have data from both tables, then you need to question the value of your `players_meta` table. It might be legitimately useful, in which case you would tell your ORM that your base query for players needs to join the `players_meta` table so you can select all the required data